# VBA: how to compare dynamic array values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

Hi everyone,
I am a novice in VBA and would be greatful for your help on the following problem:
*I have an array of strings that varies in length. I want to compare the value of each position in the array to all the positions in a different array of varying length.*
I have tried to following (comparing it to fixed values instead of an array for starters, but can't even get this to work):

```
Option Explicit
Dim subassys(counter) As Long, Filter1 As String, Filter2 As String, Filter3 As String, Filter4 As String

Sub sub_fitler ()

    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Spectrum 1"
    Range(("E2"), Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    set subassys = Selection
        Filter1 = "0"
        Filter2 = "ET"
        Filter3 = "Assy"
        Filter4 = "Normteil"
        For counter = 0 To UBound(subassys)
            If subassys(counter) = Filter1 Then
                ActiveCell.Delete
                    Exit For
            ElseIf subassys(counter) = Filter2 Then
                ActiveCell.Delete
                    Exit For
            ElseIf subassys(counter) = Filter3 Then
                ActiveCell.Delete
                Exit For
            ElseIf subassys(counter) = Filter4 Then
                ActiveCell.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next counter
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set subassys = Selection
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear
End sub
```

I feel like I am making a mistake in the declaration already - not declaring the values of the array as string. But really altogether I am not sure how to get this to work. Can anybody help me solve this? 
Jack
P.S. this is only part of the code there is other elements before and after it

Comment: If you delete an entire row or column using the [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223863(v=office.11).aspx) you don't have to provide the options **Shift** [xlDeleteShiftDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841140.aspx) since there are no real choices. However, if you are deleting a small group of cells or (as in your case) a single cell then you have to specify `Shift:=xlShiftToLeft` or `Shift:=xlShiftUp`.

Comment: What cell on worksheet **Temp** receives the .Paste? Maybe A1? This is completely up in the air.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an entire row or column using the [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223863(v=office.11).aspx) you don't have to provide the options **Shift** [xlDeleteShiftDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841140.aspx) since there are no real choices. However, if you are deleting a small group of cells or (as in your case) a single cell then you have to specify `Shift:=xlShiftToLeft` or `Shift:=xlShiftUp`.

What cell on worksheet **Temp** receives the .Paste? Maybe A1? There is no definitive cell location given; just that you start working on column A shortly after the paste.

When you delete cells in a loop, start from the bottom and work your way to the top numerically. Failing to do this may cause you to skip a cell when you delete one, everything shifts up and then you cycle on to the next cell.

I have no idea why `Dim subassys(counter) As Long` was used and then `Set` to a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). It was subsequently compared to a series of text strings. I've dimmed it as a `Range` and only used it once the comparisons (and possible cell deletions) were complete.

```
Option Explicit

Dim subassys As Range, Filters As String

Sub sub_fitler()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Data")
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Spectrum 1"
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 4).Copy _
              Destination:=Worksheets("Temp").Range("A1")
        End With
    End With
    With Worksheets("Temp")
        .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Filters = Join(Array("", "0", "ET", "Assy", "Normteil", ""), ChrW(8203))
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If CBool(InStr(1, Filters, ChrW(8203) & .Cells(rw, 1).Value2 & ChrW(8203), vbTextCompare)) Then
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
        Set subassys = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

I've changed you primary comparison to a delimited string within another deleted string. This avoids the secondary loop altogether.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thanks for your feedback! 
I don't entirely understand what setting the "filters" does (join function and ChrW(8203) in particular). Also I don't quite understand the IF function with all its attributes, therefore I copied the code that you so kindly created to test it, but I do get a compilation error (Next without For) any ideas?

Comment: Also, thx for the advise on deleting entire rows and yes, pasting into "temp", could use A1 as it is a blank sheet merely created to complete this section of the code it will be deleted afterwards.

Comment: My apologies. I misplaced an `End If`. The `Join` creates a delimited string like `×0×ET×Assy×Normteil×` and the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) checks if `×<cell value>×` is within that string.

Comment: Works great -thanks so much!
What does CHrW(8203) do?
Could I replace the values in "filters" by giving it an array of strings defined as a variable? (e.g. filters = join (array(variable_name),ChrW8203))

Comment: Also, I need to use the values stored in the 'subassy' variable to set an autofilter criteria to each value and copy the results to a different location. here is what I tried unsuccessfully so far (i am missing to tell it to use values as string and I haven't figured out the for each loop:`Sheets("BOM_data").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=subassy
        Range(("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("HTZ_global").Range("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` any ideas?

Comment: ① `ChrW(8203)` is a unicode zero-width space. A delimiter should be a character not likely to be found in your text and it seemed to be appropriate ② That sounds like a new question and not something that can be dealt with in comments.